# Spark UI Input column values are too high

Tags: apache-spark

I started a spark job and to monitor the process, I checked out the web UI that spark provides. On the executor page, I see the input as 305 GB and increasing.

On hovering over the *Input* column, I get the following description

> Bytes and records read from Hadoop or from Spark storage

My input data is only 300 MB but the *Input* column shows 305 GB. Is this expected behavior? Where is all the extra GBs of input coming from?
If not, what is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is too generic in nature. However, I will try to relate it to one of the incidents that I had. There was a similar incident that happened with me. I can share the details of my execution if that helps.

I was running a series of Spark SQL statements (with Joins and filters) and the job wasn't completing at all. Upon careful analysis in the Spark Web UI, I realized that the Input to one of the stages was running into GBs where as my data was just too small (less than 100 MB).

I checked the SQL queries and debugged at the data level only to realize that one of the JOINS was causing the issue. There was a cartesian join that was getting formed due to which the no of records shot upto millions. This resulting in run time data creation due to erroneous join condition. Once the join was fixed the issue got resolved.

Please check your code. You might get more insights. Spark on its own will not create data.